# Referencing ids for an included layout

Tags: android, layout

If I have a layout with two ImageViews.  Their id's are image_one and image_two.

Then I have a layout that includes the above layout two times.  Their id's can be layout_one and layout_two.

So this means that I have two image_one's and two image_two's.  How do I reference image_one in layout_two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `layout_two.findViewById(image_one);`